# Resizing of ArrayDeque

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, arraydeque

Quote: `Default initial capacity of ArrayDeque is 16. It will increase at a power of 2 (24, 25, 26 and so on) when size exceeds capacity.`

Does this mean it behaves similar to `ArrayList`? Each time size exceeds capacity there is new **array** where older elements are copied to? Can I say internal implementation of `ArrayDequeue` and `ArrayList` is **array** (as their name says)? Just the resizing differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `ArrayDeque` behaves similarly to `ArrayList`: Internally it uses an Object array. If the capacity is not enough, it creates a new, larger array, and copies items from the old array to the new.

The Java API specification does not require any particular resizing behavior. In fact the current implementation in OpenJDK [doubles the size of the array if it's small (64), otherwise it grows by 50%](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9d764ee48ee7c2e7be7a25aee2ed7bed2fcd2000/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#L140):

```
    // Double capacity if small; else grow by 50%
    int jump = (oldCapacity < 64) ? (oldCapacity + 2) : (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

It seems that the"doubling" behavior is approximate: thanks to the "+2" after the first resize the capacity is 16+16+2 = 34. After the second resize it's 34+34+2 = 70. After that the array increases by 50% in every resize.